# Can someone explain this PromQL query to me?

Tags: api, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm new to promQL and I am using it to create grafana dashboard to visualize various API metrics like throughput, latency etc.

For measuring latency I came across these queries being used together. Can someone explain how are they working

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(irate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="<API Endpoint>"}[2m])*30) by (path,le))

histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(irate(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="<API Endpoint>"}[2m])*30) by (path,le))
```

Also I want to write a query which will show me number of API calls with latency greater than 4sec. Can someone please help me there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided queries are designed to return 99th and 95th [percentiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) for the `http_request_duration_seconds{path="..."}` metric of [histogram type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) over requests received during the last 2 minutes (see `2m` in square brackets).

Unfortunately the provided queries have some issues:

- They use `irate()` function for calculating the per-second increase rate of every bucket defined in `http_request_duration_seconds` histogram. This function isn't recommended to use in general case, because it tends to return jumpy results on repeated queries - see [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832) for details. So it is better to use [rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) or [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) instead when calculating [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile).
- They multiply the calculated `irate()` by 30. This has no any effect on query results, since `histogram_quantile()` normalizes the provided per-bucket values.

So it is recommended to use the following query instead:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99,
  sum(
    increase(http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="..."}[2m])
  ) by (le)
)
```

This query works in the following way:

1. Prometheus selects all the time series matching the `http_request_duration_seconds_bucket{path="..."}` [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) on the selected time range on the graph. These time series represent histogram buckets for the `http_request_duration_seconds` [histogram](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram). Each such bucket contains a [counter](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#counter), which counts the number of requests with duration not exceeding the value specified in the `le` label.
2. Prometheus calculates the [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) over the last 2 minutes per each selected time series, e.g. how many requests hit every bucket during the last 2 minutes.
3. Prometheus calculates per-`le` sums over bucket values calculated at step 2 - see [sum() function docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) for details.
4. Prometheus calculates the **estimated** 99th percentile for the bucket results returned at step 3 by executing [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile) function. The error of the estimation depends on the number of buckets and the `le` values. More buckets with better `le` distribution usually give lower error for the estimated percentile.